# Indefinite Integral of $(x\,dx-y\,dy)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

The indefinite integral of $x\,dx-y\,dy$ is $\frac{x^2-y^2}{2}$. But my book work the solution to be $x^2-y^2$. Who is correct?

Comment: You are${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  The book is wrong.

Comment: There could also be some dispute with this solution.
du=[(x^2+y^2)/y]dx
The solution u is u = (x^(3)/3y)+yx+c.
Is this correct?

Comment: @user, where is $\mathrm{d}y$?